# How to remove a content from xml document by matching content value using xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

XML is like below

```
<document><content name="State">Tripura</content><content name="District">West Tripura</content><content name="Year">2005</content><content name="January">N.A.</content><content name="February">5.8</content><content name="March">199.4</content><content name="April">99.8</content><content name="May">317.1</content><content name="June">166.5</content><content name="July">317.7</content><content name="August">403.3</content><content name="September">286.8</content><content name="October">200.9</content><content name="November">0</content><content name="December">0.6</content><content name="Annual_Total">N.A.</content></document>
```

i want to ignore the content from document where content ="N.A." using xsl. Has anyone know how to do this, i am new to XSL.

I want output in following format.

```
<document><content name="State">Tripura</content><content name="District">West Tripura</content><content name="Year">2005</content><content name="February">5.8</content><content name="March">199.4</content><content name="April">99.8</content><content name="May">317.1</content><content name="June">166.5</content><content name="July">317.7</content><content name="August">403.3</content><content name="September">286.8</content><content name="October">200.9</content><content name="November">0</content><content name="December">0.6</content></document>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a "recursive copy" with an extra template to exclude the stuff you don't want

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

<xsl:output method="xml"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[. = 'N.A.']"/>
</xsl:transform>
```